# Odd HTTP URI Requests with Misplaced Periods

Tags: php, url, url-routing

I received an error report from my system because of a request that looked like this:

https://www.example.com./

Note the added period before the third forward-slash.

I would not imagine this to be valid though the server says the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = www.example.net.`.

- Is this technically valid?
- Should I be using `trim` with odd characters to redirect to the *actual* host name URLs?
- Are there other odd ways that an `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` could be requested that I should try to have my system compensate for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it's valid! check out https://stackoverflow.com./.
2. Technically I believe the URIs are identical, so I don't know there's a strong reason to redirect from one to the other. If it works, I don't think I would touch this. Note that stackoverflow for example does not.
3. The HTTP `Host` header is controlled by the client and could be any string. So if you're doing anything with that header, such as adding it to your HTML or a SQL string, you need to treat it like user input and escape. You should assume this for *every* header. It's always possible to do a request with CURL and change any of them.

Comment: Interesting in regards to Stack. I was hoping for an official reference somewhere... I'm well aware that all PHP `$_SERVER` that start with `HTTP_` are from the client; anything in *any* regards gets escaped before interacting with databases.

Comment: The reason `.` is a thing is because (for example) your `resolv.conf` might be set up with a 'search domain', which could under some circumstances postfix unknown domains with whatever domain you setup here. The `.` guarantees that this doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm not familiar, could you please edit in an example?

Comment: For example, if my `search` is set to `example.org`, and I hit a DNS name `bar`, and it doesn't exist, then `bar.example.org` will immediately be tried next.

Comment: Sorry, I've been up all night - what is a search domain? Like trying to resolve domains and subdomains on the server...?

Comment: I tried to explain this in my last 2-3 comments, but here's another resource that goes into it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/584054/how-do-i-configure-the-search-domain-correctly

Comment: I don't see any answers with your user name there. I'm going to use regex to trim all non-alphanumeric characters if an account is not found.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you're saying...

Comment: Oh, *comments* though even expanding comments I don't see your name any where on that page.

Comment: I was talking about my comments in this thread. The link I sent is just additional background information about `search`.